# Slick sometimes shows all elements on top of each other when the carousel is within a transitioning element

Tags: javascript, slick.js

So I have a cart, that when opened, transitions from right to left about 400px.

Within that cart, there is an upsell with items that's a carousel made with Slick.js.

The problem is that when the transition happens, sometimes the items get stacked on top of each other. At first I thought that the problem was with Slick itself, but I later discovered that it is the transition causing the issue.

I discovered that as I was writing this post, so I will not have much code in it.

What I have done to prove this is to initialize Slick only after the transition ends:

```js
    $('cartselector').on('transitionend", (event) => {
        $('cartupsellselector').slick();
    });
```

And after I did this, voilà, the cart transitions and then Slick initializes and never bugs up. But of course, that makes for a bad user experience.

The question that I have now: is there a way to fix this with Slick itself, or do I have to put some pre-loader or something while the cart transitions, and then remove it and show the upsell with the carousel?

Comment: Slick has trouble with creating slideshows that are hidden (assuming that's what you're doing with the transition). One thing you might try is to initialize the slideshow when you create the page and then use `$("#cartupsellselector").slick("refresh")` to fix the slideshow...this should be quicker than initializing.

Comment: Hi Ed, I have tried that, refresh has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, by first opening the popup, placing a loading placeholder in the place of the carousel, and as soon as the transition ends (detected by the `transitionend` event), I show the carousel and load it. The placeholder is barely visible for a fraction of the second, but it no longer breaks the carousel.